# Generate transitive closure only with graphviz tools

Tags: graphviz

I'd need to process a directed graph in dot format and get the transitive closure of the subgraph (actually one node).

For instance, given

```
 A -> B;
 E -> B;
 B -> C;
 C -> D;
```

I'd like to get the transitive closure of the subgraph formed by the node A:

```
 A -> B;
 B -> C;
 C -> D;
```

I know this is possible in python and a lot of other language but I am trying to achieve this using command line graphviz tools only.

Is there any simple way to do it ? (I *did* rtfm of dot, tred, patchwork… without any luck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gvpr](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) should be able to perform this task. Now I'll try it...

*edit* Not really easy, but this could be a starting point

-- file closure.gprv

```
BEGIN {
 int to_visit[];
 void add_req(node_t N) {
  edge_t e;
  for (e = fstout(N); e; e = nxtout(e))
   to_visit[e.head.name] = 1;
 }
}

BEG_G {
 $tvtype = TV_fwd;
 $tvroot = node($, "A");
 to_visit[$tvroot.name] = 1;
 add_req($tvroot);
 graph_t g = graph("A closure", "D");
}

N {
 if (to_visit[$.name]) {
  copy(g, $);
  add_req($);
 }
}

END_G {
 $O = g;
}
```

-- file closure.gv

```
digraph closure {
 A -> B;
 E -> B;
 B -> C;
 C -> D;
}
```

-- command and result

```
gvpr -f closure.gprv closure.gv
digraph "A closure" {
    A;
    B;
    C;
    D;
}
```

*edit* this other version is more complete, as it builds the edges too

```
BEGIN {
 int to_visit[];
 void add_req(node_t N) {
  edge_t e;
  for (e = fstout(N); e; e = nxtout(e))
   to_visit[e.head.name] = 1;
 }
}

BEG_G {
 $tvtype = TV_fwd;
 $tvroot = node($, "A");
 to_visit[$tvroot.name] = 1;
 add_req($tvroot);
 graph_t g = graph("A closure", "D");
}

E {
 if (to_visit[$.tail.name]) {
  copy(g, $);
  add_req($.head);
 }
}

END_G {
 $O = g;
}
```

yields

```
gvpr -f closure.gprv closure.gv
digraph "A closure" {
    A -> B;
    B -> C;
    C -> D;
}
```

Comment: thanks! is there any way to keep the properties of the nodes (like colors, shape…)

Comment: from docs I understood that `copy` should work: `creates a copy of object x in graph g, where the new object has the same name/value attributes as the original object.`. There is also clone or copyA, but I don't know about the behaviour...